# is possible to avoid declaring an object as final?

Tags: java

I'm adding a `ChangeListener` to a `JTabbedPane` in the constructor of a `JFrame`. Inside the `stateChanged` method I have a method with a parameter that I receive in the constructor, but it need to be `final`. Is it possible to avoid this?

```
 public PerfilPaciente(int operation, Patient patient) {
 tabPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            switch (tabPane.getSelectedIndex()) {
                case 1:
                    loadDates(patient);   // here is the problem
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No it's not. You've to declare local variable `final`, if you're using it in some inner class.

Comment: Why you'd like to avoid it?

Comment: @Christian I've wanted to avoid it before. Firstly, it's visual noise that the compiler shouldn't need. But more importantly, anything in a public method's declaration is part of the class's public API. Putting `final int operation` in there means that `final` is part of that public API, but this is _always_ meaningless to a reader of that API, since Java is pass-by-value; the fact that the arg is `final` is only useful to the implementation details of the method. I don't like cluttering the signature with no-op modifiers.

Comment: @yshavit good point, I think it was a mistake in the language design to put `final` in the signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Up to Java 7 (inclusive) variables used inside an anonymous class need to be explictly final. In your case:

```
public PerfilPaciente(int operation, final Patient patient) {
```

With Java 8 this is not required any longer, the variable only needs to be effectively final (i.e. never reassigned in the enclosing method). So with Java 8 your code would compile.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that feature of Java 8, well i'll declare it final until Java 8 comes out. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón Java 8 is out!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, you can create an inner class that holds the information to process

```
public class MyOutterClass {
     ...

     public PerfilPaciente(int operation, Patient patient) {
         tabPane.addChangeListener(new MyChangeListener(patient));
     }

     ...

     //use an inner class that implements the interface
     //instead of an anonymous class declaration
     private class MyChangeListener implements ChangeListener {

         Patient patient;

         public MyChangeListener(Patient patient){
             this.patient= patient;
         }

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                switch (tabPane.getSelectedIndex()) {
                    case 1:
                        loadDates(patient);   // here is the problem
                        break;
                }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand the reasons why you don't want to make it final, but you could just make a copy of that variable:

```
final Patient patientFinal = patient;
```

And then

```
loadDates(patientFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

There a way to avoid it - declare new class MyChangeListener extends ChangeListener(code like @Sam), but I doubt it's more elegant one. Anyway patient is effectively final, and it's a good practice to put final explicitly.

```
public PerfilPaciente(int operation, Patient patient) {
tabPane.addChangeListener(new MyChangeListener(patient));
}
```